# manually change kendo ui toolbar toggle button not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Kendo UI Version 2015.2.805

Toolbar toggle button

per docs:

```
var checked = true;

var tb = $("#filter_toolbar").data("kendoToolBar");
tb.toggle("#mostRecent", checked);
```

should toggle button on if checked=true and off is checked=false, however what it actually does is toggle the button irregardless of the value of checked.

That being the case,I can test for k-state-active to determine if I should toggle it or not but am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I've made a [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VlbRlE0Fh96uDe6cNAk?p=preview) with a Kendo UI Toolbar and it seems to work fine. Is there some logic to the way it does toggle the toggle button in your case?

Comment: The demo does work...I toggle the button in response to paramMap settings to keep the button in sync with the grid sort in case the user manually sorts the grid.  In debugging (chrome) in the immediate window the code above acts the same - toggles the button, seemingly ignoring the true/false even if hardcoded.  I have my workaround but this is really odd.

Comment: UPDATE: If I change the Plunker kendo.all.min to ver 2015.2.805 and change checked=false it now toggles the button!

Comment: I found this at line 88680 of the un-minified 2015.2.805 kendo.all.js: item.toggle(checked ? checked : !item.options.selected, true); which always goes to the true side, and then toggles the state...

Comment: Yeah, was just about to write the same thing. I debugged it and came to the same line. This is how they made the behavior at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in Kendo UI Q3 2015 per [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q3-2015)